# Trouble understanding invariance under the change of scale on Vertex function in Ryder's QFT textbook Equation (9.68)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, greens-functions, correlation-functions

Lewis Ryder's Quantum Field Theory textbook on page 325, states that due to the invariance under the change of scale, $p\rightarrow tp$, $m\rightarrow tm$, and $\mu \rightarrow t\mu$, the (unrenormalized) vertex function $\Gamma^n$ of mass dimension D should behave as:$$\Gamma^n(tp,g,m,\mu)=t^D\Gamma^n(p,g,m/t,\mu/t)=\mu^DF\Big(g,\frac{t^2p^2}{m\mu}\Big)$$
And from this form he infers that the vertex function must obey equation (9.68):
$$\bigg(t\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+m\frac{\partial}{\partial m}+\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}-D\bigg)\Gamma^n=0$$
I need help enabling me to follow how this relation between the scalings and $\mu$ is so evident.

Note: The same set of arguments could also be found in Michio Kaku's QFT on page 480.

Comment: I am seeking clarification on how the differential equation follows from the given form of  vertex function Gamma.

Comment: Is the differential of gamma zero? In that case it might just be some heavy use of the liebniz rule?

Comment: No, the differential of  Gamma w.r.t t depends upon the differentials of m and g as dictated by the RG equation.

Comment: Well, it almost looks like a homogenous function so perhaps that is something to google on.

Comment: Could this be relevant: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html ?

Comment: $\Gamma(tp,tm,t\mu)=t^D\Gamma(p,m,\mu)$ would fit well into that theorem. Perhaps it can be rewritten into that, I think it can.